# Insert Data Into temporary table using Select * Into

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert data into temporary table for that i am using `select * into` syntax.

But i am getting error :

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Though Single Query getting executed successful.

Code:

```
Create Table #_Total
(
A   Int,
B   Int,
C   Int,
D   Int
)

Select * InTo #_Total From(
Select 
Sum(Case When Closed=0 And ISNULL(VendorTicketNo,'')='' Then 1 Else 0 End),
Sum(Case When Closed=1 And TicketType<>8 AND ISNULL(VendorTicketNo,'')<>'' Then 1 Else 0 End),
Sum(Case When Closed=1 And CAST(ClosedOn As DATE)= CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),112) Then 1 Else 0 End),
Sum(Case When Closed=0 And TicketType=8 Then 1 Else 0 End)
From ALBATMStatus.dbo.Ticket
)

Select * From #_Total
```

Database - SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: You don't use existing table for Select * INTO. Delete that table and try executing the query again. Or you need to use Insert Into statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are creating the table before hand, you have to use

```
INSERT INTO
```

Try this

```
Create Table #_Total
(
A   Int,
B   Int,
C   Int,
D   Int
)

Insert Into #_Total 
Select * From(
Select 
Sum(Case When Closed=0 And ISNULL(VendorTicketNo,'')='' Then 1 Else 0 End),
Sum(Case When Closed=1 And TicketType<>8 AND ISNULL(VendorTicketNo,'')<>'' Then 1 Else 0 End),
Sum(Case When Closed=1 And CAST(ClosedOn As DATE)= CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),112) Then 1 Else 0 End),
Sum(Case When Closed=0 And TicketType=8 Then 1 Else 0 End)
From ALBATMStatus.dbo.Ticket
) AS a

Select * From #_Total
```

Raj

Answer (score 1):

As @Raj said you either use `Create` or `select into`.

However he missed `as ALIAS_NAME`. It is as below :

```
Create Table #_Total
(
A   Int,
B   Int,
C   Int,
D   Int
)

Insert Into #_Total 
Select * From(
Select 
Sum(Case When Closed=0 And ISNULL(VendorTicketNo,'')='' Then 1 Else 0 End) A,
Sum(Case When Closed=1 And TicketType<>8 AND ISNULL(VendorTicketNo,'')<>'' Then 1 Else 0 End) B,
Sum(Case When Closed=1 And CAST(ClosedOn As DATE)= CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),112) Then 1 Else 0 End) C,
Sum(Case When Closed=0 And TicketType=8 Then 1 Else 0 End) D
From ALBATMStatus.dbo.Ticket
) as q1

Select * From #_Total
```

Comment: Good catch. I actually copied the code and changed Select into to Insert into. Did not test the code.